# Conditional Formatting for a dynamic table of data in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following function in A15

`=FILTER(FILTER(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Project Name]=A2), {1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1})`

And the conditional formatting Rule

`=MOD(ROW(),2)=0`

Applied to

`=$A$15:$F$22`

as set out in the image

[image: Conditional Format]

Is there a way to make the conditional formatting continue to work as the data gets bigger and only if there's something in the row?

Comment: Is there any other data table below this one or could you theoretically apply the conditional formatting to all rows of those columns?

Comment: There is nothing below so that would be possible. Is there a way to only format if there’s something in that row?

Comment: Note that it would slow your file down. How important is the formatting compared to calculation speed?

Comment: I guess I could see how it goes and if it causes a problem then I’ll have to live with it for the empty rows too

Comment: fixed with =AND($A15<>"",MOD(ROW(),2)=0)

Answer (score 0):

Used the following formula to check if there is no entry in the first column to determine whether to use the conditional formatting to set the row colour, ultimtely stopping after the last row with valid data in it.

`=AND($A15<>"",MOD(ROW(),2)=0)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).